# CSS, How make a icon behind a link and the link still be clickable

Tags: html, css

I'm able to make the icon behind the link, but can't make it clickable anymore.

I already used `z-index` property. but I had no luck.

Can someone help me, find out a way an icon to be behind the link and link be still clickable?

**PS**: I can click the link only in the corners.

Here's the snippet of the problem:

```css
.menu-expanded{ 
    background-color: #F16136;
    background-image: linear-gradient(transparent 4%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9) 1%);
    background-size: 50px 30px;
    max-height: 250px;
    min-height: 250px;
   opacity: 1;
    
}
.menu-itens{
    position:absolute;
    padding-left:70px;
}

i{
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0.35;
}
ul{
    list-style-type:none;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
ul  li{
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
 
}
ul  li a{
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  font-size: 1.0em;
  color: #55D;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  line-height: 1.8em;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  line-height: 2.5em;
}

a:hover{
  color:#00405d;
  text-decoration:underline;
}

.rightpercent10{
   right:10%;
}
.rightpercent20{
   right:20%;
}
.rightpercent40{
   right:40%;
}
.rightpercent50{
   right:50%;
}
.leftpercent10{
   left:10%;
}
.leftpercent20{
   left:20%;
}
.leftpercent40{
   left:40%;
}
.leftpercent13{
   left:13%;
}
.padtpercent6{
    padding-top:6%;
}
.padtpercent11{
    padding-top:11%;
}
.padtpercent5{
    padding-top:5%;
}
.padtpercent2{
    padding-top:2%;
}
.padtpercent12{
    padding-top:12%;
}
.padtpercent13{
    padding-top:13%;
}
.padtpercent10{
    padding-top:10%;
}
.padtpercent20{
    padding-top:20%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div ng-init="bindMenuEvent()" ng-show="menu.show" id="menu-expanded" class="menu-expanded" style="">
  <!-- start header menu -->
  <div ng-show="menu.name==='camisas'" class="menu-itens camisas" style="">
   <!-- ngRepeat: (key, value) in loja.gender --><div class="item ng-scope" ng-repeat="(key, value) in loja.gender">
    <div class="header_nav">
     <h4 ng-bind="key" class="ng-binding">masculine</h4>
     <ul>
      <li><a ng-click="clickLinkMenu()" ng-href="/#!/products/gender/masculino" href="/#!/products/gender/masculino">All  models</a></li>
      <!-- ngRepeat: typeClothes in value --><li ng-repeat="typeClothes in value" class="ng-scope">
       <a ng-click="clickLinkMenu()" ng-href="/#!/Regata/masculino" ng-bind="typeClothes" class="ng-binding" href="/#!/Regata/masculino">Regata</a>
      </li><!-- end ngRepeat: typeClothes in value --><li ng-repeat="typeClothes in value" class="ng-scope">
       <a ng-click="clickLinkMenu()" ng-href="/#!/Camiseta/masculino" ng-bind="typeClothes" class="ng-binding" href="/#!/Camiseta/masculino">Camiseta</a>
      </li><!-- end ngRepeat: typeClothes in value -->

     </ul> 
    </div>       
   </div><!-- end ngRepeat: (key, value) in loja.gender -->
   <!-- ngRepeat: (key, value) in loja.collection -->
  </div>
  <i class="fa fa-music fa-4x rightpercent10 padtpercent6"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-music fa-3x rightpercent20 padtpercent11"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-music fa-4x rightpercent40 padtpercent5"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-music fa-5x rightpercent50 padtpercent2"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-music fa-5x leftpercent13 padtpercent20"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-music fa-2x leftpercent20 padtpercent13"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-music fa-4x leftpercent13 padtpercent10"></i>
   
</div>
```

Comment: your icons doesnt show.

Comment: can't you see the music icon? <i class="fa fa-music fa-4x rightpercent10 padtpercent6"></i>

Comment: it loads now. excuse me. its my network restriction.

Comment: `text-transform: capitalize` doesn't do anything; you probably meant `text-transform: uppercase`.

Comment: @MrLister yep! thanks didnt notice that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apply `pointer-events: none` to the icons.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.item{
  position: relative;
z-index: 99999;
  }
```

Reset the css style given above , it was working fine....

Comment: There's no need to abuse z-indexes like that. `z-index:1` would have worked as well.